# How to set conditional breakpoint in anonymous inner class depending on final local variable?

Tags: java, eclipse, conditional-breakpoint, anonymous-inner-class

suppose I have the following class and want to set a conditional breakpoint on arg==null at the marked location. This won't work in eclipse and gives the error "conditional breakpoint has compilation error(s). Reason: arg cannot be resolved to a variable".

I found some related information [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F), but even if I change the condition to "val$arg==null" (val$arg is the variable name displayed in the debugger's variable view), eclipse gives me the same error.

```
public abstract class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = foo("123");
        Test t2 = foo(null);
        t1.bar();
        t2.bar();
    }

    abstract void bar();

    static Test foo(final String arg) {
        return new Test() {
            @Override 
                void bar() {
                // I want to set a breakpoint here with the condition "arg==null"
                System.out.println(arg); 
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try placing the argument as a field in the local class.

```
static Test foo(final String arg) {
    return new Test() {
        private final String localArg = arg;
        @Override 
            void bar() {
            // I want to set a breakpoint here with the condition "arg==null"
            System.out.println(localArg); 
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can only offer an ugly workaround:

```
if (arg == null) {
     int foo = 0; // add breakpoint here
}
System.out.println(arg);
```

Comment: conditional breakpoints *kill* performance, so the workaround is not *that* ugly in my eyes...

Comment: I often use Thread.yield() as a breakpoint because I have a check which scans for this code to make sure its not released.

Comment: This is not always an option (ie when the class is defined in a separate Jar file), and you'd have to change the code back after debugging. As a workaround, I often change the code like this (and leave it in): String myArg = arg; System.out.println(myArg);

Comment: @Peter, could you elaborate on "make sure it is not released"?

Comment: @Axel, lots of print statements is a nuisance when running in a debug console.  Could you use a logger instead?

Comment: @Bozho, I do not think that is ugly.  If it is a special case you need to take action on it anyway.

Comment: I have a maven build which performs some checks on a release.

Comment: I would add that when trying to track an inavlid value its best to fail fast.  I would suggest placing the breakpoint on the return statement (so you can see why the value is null) if not a check for null which throws an exception.

Comment: @Thorbjorn: This is a simplified Test class I created to show the actual problem in a compact form with a working (compilable) example. The real code doesn't contain any output statements.